# Java bytecode beginner questions: order of "istore" variable usage, "byte usage" etc

Tags: java, bytecode

I have the following Java code:

```
public static void fun(int[] a) {

    int min;

    for(int j=0;j<a.length-1;j++) {
        min=j;

        for(int i=j+1;i<a.length;i++) 
            if(a[i]<a[min]) min=i;

        if(min!=j) {
            int temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[min];
            a[min]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I have used `javap -c` on the class file generated by the above code to print the Java bytecode for the above program and I get the output below:

> 0: iconst_0
> 1: istore_2
> 2: iload_2
> 3: aload_0
> 4: arraylength
> 5: iconst_1
> 6: isub
> 7: if_icmpge  64
> 10: iload_2
> 11: istore_1
> 12: iload_2
> 13: iconst_1
> 14: iadd
> 15: istore_3
> 16: iload_3
> 17: aload_0
> 18: arraylength
> 19: if_icmpge  39
> 22: aload_0
> 23: iload_3
> 24: iaload
> 25: aload_0
> 26: iload_1
> 27: iaload
> 28: if_icmpge  33
> 31: iload_3
> 32: istore_1
> 33: iinc 3, 1
> 36: goto 16
> 39: iload_1
> 40: iload_2
> 41: if_icmpeq  58
> 44: aload_0
> 45: iload_2
> 46: iaload
> 47: istore_3
> 48: aload_0
> 49: iload_2
> 50: aload_0
> 51: iload_1
> 52: iaload
> 53: iastore
> 54: aload_0
> 55: iload_1
> 56: iload_3
> 57: iastore
> 58: iinc 2, 1
> 61: goto 2
> 64: return

My question relates mainly to the `istore` command. As you can see, at "1:", the bytecode generated is `istore_2`. Why, in this case, is `istore_2` used, rather than `istore_0` or `istore_1`? As we can see, later, at "11:", `istore_1` is used, however, `istore_0` is not. Is there a reason for this, why variable 2 is used at the start and variable 1 is used later?

Apologies if the above is worded badly, I am only beginning to learn Java bytecode in college at the moment.

Additionally, I am trying to figure out which commands use more than one byte from the list we have to learn to use. This is the list, can somebody verify if the "byte usage" (I'm not sure of the correct term) is correct on the commands  below (we have to convert by hand in the exam, using the command list given below and I need to learn how many bytes each command uses - it was explained very badly and quickly in our lectures and there are no online notes for it from the lecturer).

> "aload_n" - 1 byte 
> "iconst_n" - 1 byte 
> "iaload"- 1 byte 
> "istore_n"- 1 byte 
> "arraylength"- 1 byte 
> "if_icmpge"- 3 bytes 
> "if_icmple"- 3 bytes 
> "iinc i c" - unsure? 3 bytes? 
> "goto n" - 3 bytes? 
> "ireturn" - 1 byte

Finally, I believe that `goto n` uses 3 bytes (as stated above), however, can someone please explain why this is the case?

Thank you so much for your help, I realise that this is a long question!
Lauren

Comment: "I need to learn how many bytes each command uses", - my condolences for having to master such a useless skill. Anyway there is a great commands list at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) which explains this theme very well.

Comment: Thanks for this, and thank you for your condolences!

Comment: What class is this? This is pretty much only useful if you're writing a Java compiler. At any rate, you can find out everything in the JVM specification.

Comment: Language Design and Compilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the byte usage, you can consult the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html). Quoting from the notes at the beginning: *"Each cell in the instruction format diagram represents a single 8-bit byte"* so it should be easy to get the size for each instruction.

> As you can see, at "1:", the bytecode generated is "istore_2". Why, in this case, is "istore_2" used, rather than "istore_0" or "istore_1"?

Simply because at line 1, the bytecode is storing a value of zero to the local variable `j` which happens to be at index 2. Similarly `istore_1` stores the value on the operand stack to the local variable at index 1 (in this case, `min`).

This works because, long story short, every method is allocated a stack frame with [local variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) in it, accessible by indices that are assigned at compile-time.

For the `goto` instruction, this is also in the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto):

> *goto*
>
> *branchbyte1*
>
> *branchbyte2*
>
> The unsigned bytes *branchbyte1* and *branchbyte2* are used to construct a signed 16-bit *branchoffset*, where *branchoffset* is (*branchbyte1* << 8) | *branchbyte2*. Execution proceeds at that offset from the address of the opcode of this *goto* instruction. The target address must be that of an opcode of an instruction within the method that contains this *goto* instruction.

There are two bytes after the opcode, which compose the 16-bit offset. The resulting target address is computed as:

> target_address = address_of_current_goto + 16_bit_offset

Comment: Is there a reason why index 2 is used at line 1 through? Why isn't index 0 used at line 1, since this is the first instance of local variable storage? Thanks for your help! 

EDIT: Also, I still do not understand why goto needs three bytes. I can see that there is one for the command and one for the branch number given after the command, however, what does the third byte do and what does goto do with it?

Comment: @LaurenHayes The compiler translated the parameter `a` into a LV and placed it in a table at index 0, then translated `min` into a LV at index 1, and so on (this makes sense given the order in the program code). It then happens that the first instruction deals with `j` (assigned at index 2).

Comment: Oh, hang on, so the compiler basically "assigns" (or "sets aside") the LV at index 1 to `min`, but doesn't do anything with it yet because it isn't initialized and then goes on to store 0 in LV 2 for the `j` variable in the for loop declaration, then later it stores values in the LV at 1 for `min`?

EDIT: Also, regarding `goto`, I am aware it is in the specification, however, I do not understand what it is doing and what `branchbyte1` and `branchbyte2` are and what `goto` is doing with them. Could you possibly elaborate? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @LaurenHayes Yes. I would think of the local variable table creation as an independent step which happens before generating the instructions. The instructions then refer to these local variables, and execute what you pretty much described.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense to me now, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. The `goto` offset is 16-bit. That's why it takes two bytes.